# created_by and updated_by fields in Models.py

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

how to implement created_by and updated_by fields in my models.py and also when do i pass models.created_by and updated_by == request.user in my views.py?

please can anyone help me to do from scratch

Comment: Please do share your models.py and also explain at what event you want to store `created_by` and `updated_by` ?